# Reading key-value pair in Bash where value contains delimiter

Tags: bash

How to read a key-value pair file into an associative array when the value portion may have the delimiter in the value? So, split the line on the first occurrence of the delimiter, and store in an associative array.

Example KVP file contents:

```
key=value
key1=[SHA:]$value()%_&+=
```

I'd like to do something like

```
KVP_FILE="./file.properties"
declare -A keyvals
while read line; do 
 ??
 keyvals[$key]="$value"
done < $KVP_FILE
```

This is a broken code sample which loses the trailing `=` in the `key1` from the file sample above.

```
while IFS=$'=' read key value; do
     [[ $key = [#!]* ]] || [[ $key = "" ]] && continue;
     keyvals[$key]=$(echo "$value" | sed 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')
   done < $SFILE
```

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) interest yourself in [IFS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)

Comment: @KamilCuk I see your message. I'm struggling with how to split, but only on first delimiter. (I had to edit my example file to show the trailing '=' which which I do not want to lose).

Comment: Och indeed, you are right, `IFS== read` would remove the trailing separators. Puff, so we have to do it another way.

Comment: Ouch indeed ;-)  I would preprocess the KVPfile to add specialized tokens (maybe html codes?) for any shell syntax chars that are in the value side. Then you when you used the value, you'll have to undo that (and guard it from the shell interpter). Why do you want to do this ;-? ) . Good luck!

Comment: It's a good question. There is a file which is updated with connection information and those values are placed into other configuration files through this script. There could be URLs with & being replaced into the configurations with sed, for example. There could be connection key hashes with many = on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use parameter expansion to remove everything *starting with* the first `=` for the key, and everything *up to* the first `=` for the value:

```
declare -A keyvals

while IFS= read -r line; do
    keyvals["${line%%=*}"]=${line#*=}
done < "$KVP_FILE"
```

Comment: unfortunately keyvals["${line%%=*}"]: bad array subscript

Comment: My mistake! As you can see in my original question, I had a line to skip comments and blank lines, but mistakenly removed it when I was trying your solution. I think your solution is correct for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to replace first separator to a newline. Then read two lines at a time.

```
KVP_FILE="./file.properties"
declare -A keyvals
while read -r key && read -r value; do 
   keyvals[$key]="$value"
done < <(sed 's/=/\n/' "$KVP_FILE")
```

Comment: seems to be a syntax error in the done line. But I'm not quite sure what the intention is with the < <

Comment: The `<` redirects the file. The `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I found Benjamin's solution to work, in the meantime, however.